# Using xmlhttprequest in vba, How do I get elements that dont load in the initial request

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-teams

I am trying to interact with the chat screen of Microsoft teams using xmlhttprequests within vba. I am new to xmlhttprequest (xmlhr) and I am stuck at a point where the majority of the page has loaded but not the chat window. I can use .getelementbyid to get the flex-fill element but it doesn't have the divs or any messages in the responseText.

I assume it is waiting for the inner frame to load or to be visible, but I don't know how to call a second request without using a new xmlhttprequest.

I am using:

```
Dim myUrl as string
MyUrl = "https://teams.microsoft.com/_?tenantid=xxxxx"
Dim xmlhttp as new MSXML2.xmlhttp60
Xmlhttp.open "get", myUrl, false
Xmlhttp.setrequestheader "content-type", "Application/xml"
Xmlhttp.send

Dim html as new htmldocument
Html.body.innerhtml = xmlhttp.responsetext
Set testing = html.getelementbyid(=page-content-wrapper")
'this works fine but there are no children past the next child
```

When I look at the developer tool for the site, the messages are in this element but in the xmlhttprequest I can only see the outermost frame of the chat window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"How do I get elements that dont load in the initial request"* - Using XMLHTTPRequest (or its cousins), you can't. Look into tapping into the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object.

Comment: The issue is that I need to do this without IE running. I am very familiar with IE automation but it doesn't work for my situation. Is it possible to work this so that it is running as code rather than as an ie application?

Comment: Not with any degree of practicality. Either you use a full browser (IE is just one of the options, but it integrates very well into the tools you have available in VBA), or you re-implement the entire client application from scratch using XMLHTTPRequests, which could be more painful than you would currently be able to imagine. I'd go with the browser automation approach, if I had to decide.

Comment: Sadly teams does not work on IE anymore which means implemnting seleniumbasic. This is a corporate settings and installing selenium would not be viable.

Comment: I understand that this involves asking people questions. But if they say no, then it can't be done, it's as simple as that. If they want it to be done, they will have to say yes.

Comment: Speaking of MS Teams. Teams has an API, you don't have to automate a browser for that. Accessing an API can be done with XMLHTTPRequests. That might involve asking different people *different* questions, but on the technical level it has a higher chance of success.

Comment: Painful I think will be the experience and if you can't install selenium, will you be able to interact with the APIs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0 Apparently there are webhooks too e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook

Comment: @DrKEWatson - Please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Comment: No. It hasn't. It seems it is doable. You just have to get the skype token for the session then call a poll xhr that teams uses. I will post back once I have a working code